# Regex remove previous character if followed by a character

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I'm working on a regex expression. I have two words 1234a and 1234. If ‘a’ is there I want it to return just 123. If ‘a’ is not there then I want it to return 1234.

Since regex engine starts from left to right position, I can’t backtrack to remove 4 if ‘a’ is present. Is it possible to do this in regex? Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

UPDATE:Toto's answer works good.But as an extension of the above problem if the word is test1234asample I need it to return test123 if 'a' is there else if 'a' is not there return test1234.I tried to modify the regex from Toto but it highlights everything.

Comment: Do you need regex for that? You can just use `endswith`.

Comment: `re.search(r'^\d+', s).group(0)`?

Comment: This is not inside python.I'm sending the words and regex through a third party tool and get the result back.I don't have the option to do it in the script.

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/1EEQzC/1) what you want?

Comment: I think you need positive lookahead as mentioned by @Toto

Comment: If you just want to remove any character that is followed by an 'a', a simple s/.a// will replace any substring of length 2 that ends in 'a' with the empty string in the given string. Would this work, or are there additional requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tool supports lookahead, use:

```
\b([^\Wa]+(?=[^\Wa]a.*)|\w+$)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/1EEQzC/3)

Comment: Thanks for your help.It works good.As an extension of the above problem if the word is test1234asample I need it to return test123 if 'a' is there else if 'a' is not there return test1234.I'm trying to modify your regex to do that but it highlights everything.

Comment: If I try just test123asample then it highlights test12 which is correct but If I try "this is test123asample" it highlights everything before test12 too which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach than regex. For regex, you can refer to  Toto's comment/answer

```js
function getString(str) {
  return str.includes('a') ? str.substring(0, str.indexOf('a') - 1) : str;
}

let str1 = '1234a';
let str2 = '1234';
let str3 = '1234a12312';

console.log(getString(str1));
console.log(getString(str2));
console.log(getString(str3));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing the exact replacement asked for in OP's would be a simple s/.a// substitution that replaces any substring of length 2 that finishes in 'a' with the empty string. No look ahead or backtrack required.